# I am getting error :- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'C:\Users\suraj\Desktop\new\node_modules\angularfire2\database\list'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I m getting the following error while coding in angular and don't know what to do

Module not found: Error:

> Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in
>   'C:\Users\suraj\Desktop\new\Ennobleadmin\node_modules\angularfire2\database\list'

```
package.json file 
{
  "name": "ennobleadmin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^4.6.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you do the import in the correct way? import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1602

Comment: @siva636 i haven't  imported the rxjs i have imported only firebase and angularfire libraries

Answer (score 8):

In `angularfire2 v5.0.0-rc.3` is using `rxjs 5.x`. You have two way.

#### 1: Upgrade AngularFire2 Libary.

`npm install --save angularfire2@latest`

or,

#### 2: Install rxjs-compat

`npm install --save rxjs-compat`

Answer (score 2):

*update* 
`angularfire2` package has been deprecated now you should not use it.

new package name is`@angular/fire`. 
And also `npm install --save angularfire2@latest` **is not solution** for this problem as its depracated and support also not there though you can just install it and use it. 
You can use `npm install --save rxjs-compat` for deprecated version to solve this error.

For latest version please use `npm install @angular/fire`